# How do I capture a name missing column in a dataframe using pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am building a pyspark python notebook.I have a requirement to dynamically pass conditions to create new dataframe columns.This condition can include one or more other columns from the same datafarame.
However, sometimes the column may not exist in the dataframe. Then, i receive the followng error. I would like to capture and store the column that is missing. In the below case, I would like to capture 'col1'.

Since I'm passing dynamic expression, i don't know the name of column ahead.

*Column 'col1' does not exist*

If I can capture just the column name, I can create empty column and re-process it.

I couldn't find the resources on capturing this. Any one has a code to capture missing column name.

I tried to use try catch exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `try + except` here to catch all exceptions and get the ***missing column names***.

**`Example:`**

```
import re
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'Mary had a little lamb')],['Number','Keywords'])
df.printSchema()
try:
  df.select("col1").show()
except Exception as err:
  missing_col = re.findall(r"name (.*)\s+cannot be resolved", str(err).replace("\n",""))
  print(missing_col)
  #['`col1`']
```

In this example we can see `col1` not present and we are catching the column names using `re` module **(regex for python)**